# How to make interaction plots in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am in a bind.
I am trying to create an interaction plot between some variables to determine their impact on the response.

The data is at http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/nicholas.polson/teaching/41000/election2012.txt

I could not figure out how to do interaction plots in **R**, but I found a site that demonstrated a user defined function executing interaction plots:
- http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/courses/36-350.2001/lectures/day30/
The user defined functions are located [here](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/courses/36-350.2001/code/rtable.r)

Using this user defined function, I am trying to create an interaction plot with 
Response: VP
Predictors: G and P  (I would also like to include Z, but I am having enough trouble with 2 variables so I have put that on the back burner)
(VP,G,& P are columns in the initial data set above.)

Every time I try to plug in my values, **R** throws me errors, claiming objects G and P are not found etc. I also tried to use the interaction.plot function, but it would draw me a blank chart, and when I changed parameters, I would get an error claiming that a variable was an atomic vector, but when I plugged the same variable into the predict.plot function (the user defined one from the MIT site) **R** threw an error because the same variable supposedly wasn't atomic.

How can I make a 2 variable interaction plot like the one on the MIT site with my data (and if anyone is so inclined, how can I make it with 3 variables)?

Comment: this isn't quite a reproducible example.  Could you show us some code that's not working?

Comment: I have probably over 100 lines of code that are failed attempts at replicating the interaction plot on the MIT site. It will provide no value if I post my failed attempts at function calls.

Comment: When you say you are getting errors but don't show the code, there's not a lot people can do. There is no function on that page named "interaction.plot" so your statement that "using this user defined function" has no specific target. I sometimes think there should be a complete ban on the use of pronouns in technical writing.

Comment: Hello Dwin,
Interaction.Plot() is built into R, it is not user defined. Since I had trouble with it, I attempted to use the user defined interaction plot from the MIT site, which is called with the code predict.plot().

Comment: some errors i had
`> predict.plot(eldINTModel~G|P)
Error in get(given, env = data) : object 'P' not found
> predict.plot(eldINTModel~G:P)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'G' not found
> predict.plot(eldINTModel,partial=T))
Error: unexpected ')' in "predict.plot(eldINTModel,partial=T))"
> predict.plot(eldINTModel,partial=T)
plotting partial residuals
'rror in predict.plot.data.frame(data, partial = object, ...) :
 could not find function "response.var"
> eldGP=lm(VP~G+P+Z+G*P,data=eld)
> predict.plot(eldGP~G+P)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'G' not found`

Comment: eldINTModel is the linear model of my data with variables G+P as predictors. Also, "eld" is the original complete dataset. I nearly had it above, but the error "could not find function "response.var" prevented the function from running. As you can see it is a mess to sort through the errors and I simply hope someone else can look at the user defined code and show me how to apply my to my dataset.

Comment: @user1800340 You are being obtuse. You said you were getting an error with a user defined function to create an interaction plot but did not offer the code or make a specific reference to a particular function in the page you cited.

Comment: You claim that my post is missing something it clearly contains. You can repeatedly see in my posts that I am trying create an interaction plot with the user defined function predict.plot from the MIT page or with the standard interaction.plot() function in R, and I am trying to do so with the dataset I linked to.

The problem ended up being that I was incorrectly attempting to pass data frame variables into a function which required numeric variables. As is easily seen in my code, this was not obvious. Therefore my code was not of help and instead I needed a total walkthrough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
The problem was that I was attempting to pass column names from a data frame into the predict.plot and interaction.plot functions.

I had to convert the columns to matrices and then pass those matrices into the functions. Now everything works.

To convert data frames to matrices, use

MatrixVari = as.matrix(listColumni) 
where each listColumni is a column from your data frame that you then read into its own matrixVari.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following before running any further commands:

```
attach( df )
```

...assuming that your data frame with your data is called `df`.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Please hold off further replies as I found the major error in my code, this should allow me to make some significant progress.